# Elevation not working suddenly after the modification in my react-native app content which worked before

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have used elevation property in my app it was working fine before but suddenly after few other changes the elevation not working.

[image: this is old design what i wanted]

[image: New modified content]

styling i have used which worked fine before.

````
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        height: hp('9%'),
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: wp('2%'),
        marginBottom: hp('2%'),
        marginLeft: wp('5%'),
        elevation: 5,  ```
````

Comment: "few other changes" -> what changes? If this style did not change, the problem is not in this style but in your changes

Comment: Did you set  the `elevation` on the parent component?

Comment: `<View style={[styles.companyPersonSubContainer, { marginTop: hp('1%') }]} >
 <Image source={require('../icons/sam1.png')} style={styles.companyPersonIcon} />
 <View>
 <Text style={styles.companyPersonContainerSubText}>Name</Text>
 <Text style={styles.companyPersonContainerSubText2}>MD</Text>
 </View>
</View>` i have set elevation in the `companyPersonSubContainer`

Answer (score 0):

You can try "position: 'relative'" under elevation on styles.

```
flexDirection: 'row',
backgroundColor: 'white',
height: hp('9%'),
alignItems: 'center',
borderRadius: wp('2%'),
marginBottom: hp('2%'),
marginLeft: wp('5%'),
elevation: 5,
position: 'relative',
```